# Combining Partial Sum and Exponent functions

Tags: summation, exponential-function

The Challenge I am facing is combining two formulas based for a game on command and Conquer.  The Silo creates continuous productivity when left alone for a while with storage.  Only looking at the upgrade and selling cost.  In this case "tiberium"

Trying to figure out about:

```
how much each "silo" costs per level
how much total spent
how much it sells for at that level
```

etc.

found two essential formulas:

```
Partial Sum
Exponential function
```

Where Partial Sum is:

```
y=(n(n+1))/2
```

and Exponential formula

```
y=ab^x
```

where

```
y is the output.
a and b refer to the climbing curve of cost
and x which is the silo's level
n denotes infinite level of the silo base
```

For Example:

```
Upgrade Silo lv 9 to 10 costs 8800
Upgrade Silo Lv 8 to 9 costs 3200

The costs are the a and b where levels is the exponent power
```

Is this the correct way of writing the total cost of the silo at its current level? (forgive me if i dont know math shortcuts)

```
y=( ab^n ( ab^n + ab^1 ) ) / ab^2
```

If not, how do i correctly write the exponential function with the partial sum?

Comment: Your question looks like this: "is this formula correct? *follows a bunch of symbols without any explanation*". How can we say if it's correct or not? What are these $a,b,n$? What are the rules these "silo" follow?

Comment: thanks will edit

Comment: what do you mean by "a and b refer to the climbing curve of cost"? and what units is "the silo's level" measured in? and what exactly is the silo base?

Comment: currently trying to find a decent 'example' for the silos and how the levels are contributed.  i will edit an example area to describe